# Designing a general slide window program in Haskell, need type class family?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to implement a general sliding window algorithm on a list of elements. A common use case is find the largest number in all windows of length 5. Or it can count how many elements in the window is true for some predicate.

The sliding window going from left to right, and maintain some data structure. An element fall outside the window it calls `remove` on the data structure. if a new element falls within the window, we `add` the element to the data structure. It also has a function `aggregate`, which compute something on the data structure.

The naive data structure to use is a dequeue, but it's potentially possible someone want to use other kind of data structure for special use cases.

My original idea was to have a long function that looks like this

```
runSlidingWindow :: (c->(Int,a)->c)  -- add
                 -> (c->(Int,a)->c)  -- remove
                 -> (c->b)           -- aggregate
                 -> c                -- identity
                 -> Int              -- width
                 -> [(Int,a)]        -- input
                 -> [(Int,b)]
```

But I was wondering are there some Haskell way so we can define some class `Window a b c`, such that we can rewrite the function as

```
runSlidingWindow :: (Window a b c=>WindowInstance a b c)
                 -> WindowInstance a b c
                 -> [(Int,a)]
                 -> [(Int,b)]

runSlidingWindow window input
```

Of course I don't think the above is valid Haskell code. We want to force any type that is a instance of `Window a b c` to have functions of the form

```
add :: (Window a b c=>WindowInstance a b c)
    -> WindowInstance a b c
    -> a
    -> WindowInstance a b c 
remove :: (Window a b c=>WindowInstance a b c)
       -> WindowInstance a b c
       -> a
       -> WindowInstance a b c 
aggregate :: (Window a b c=>WindowInstance a b c)
          -> WindowInstance a b c
          -> b
```

So having this type class `Window a b c` is important, since this allows others to implement their own sliding windows.

I'm not aware of how this can be done in Haskell. I think using type class family this is possible? I would like to see an example.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this "window" is supposed to do, but maybe you want something like a [zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29) with a special current element?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable, but I am loathe to correct your invalid code and risk changing the meaning of your question. When you write `(Window a b c=>WindowInstance a b c)`, what do you mean by that? You say that `Window` is a class --- what is `WindowInstance`?

Comment: `WindowInstance a b c` would be a type

Comment: Oh I see, maybe I meant `(Window a b c) d`, and replace `WindowInstance a b c` with `d` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you think “I need a typeclass”, stop, and consider whether a record of functions would do.

```
data Window a b c = Window {
    add       :: c -> (Int, a) -> c,
    remove    :: c -> (Int, a) -> c,
    aggregate :: c -> b,
    identity  :: c,
    width     :: Int}

runSlidingWindow :: Window a b c -> [(Int, a)] -> [(Int, b)]
```

Or even, hiding the implementation type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Window a b = forall c. Window {
    add       :: c -> (Int, a) -> c,
    remove    :: c -> (Int, a) -> c,
    aggregate :: c -> b,
    identity  :: c,
    width     :: Int}

runSlidingWindow :: Window a b -> [(Int, a)] -> [(Int, b)]
```

Comment: Could you expand on using a record of functions over a typeclass please? (Or provide a link)

Comment: A typeclass is essentially a way to make a record of functions available to values constrained to types of the given class. The unique property of typeclasses is the polymorphism they provide: which set of functions (known as a dictionary) is used is decided by the type.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html) to a post I wrote describing the type classes as records in more detail.  Another good post is [this one](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) by Luke Palmer.

Answer (score 5):

Typeclasses are best used when you have a reasonable expectation that there is a (near) one-to-one correspondence between types and implementations. While `newtype` wrappers enable one to expose multiple instances for a given type, relying on this too often is a sign that the semantics of the class are underspecified. Many Haskellers will give more formal laws to a typeclass to better specify its semantics (that being said, ambiguous cases will still exist: e.g. the `Applicative` instances of `[]` and `ZipList`).

To expand further upon the equivalence of typeclasses and records of functions, when you write a typeclass declaration,

```
class MyNum t where
    add    :: t -> t -> t
    mul    :: t -> t -> t

instance MyNum Int where
    add = (+)
    mul = (*)
```

You can equivalently write this as a record (dictionary) of functions,

```
data MyNumDict t = MyNumDict { add :: t -> t -> t
                             , mul :: t -> t -> t
                             }

intDict :: MyNumDict Int
intDict = MyNumDict { add = (+)
                    , mul = (*)
                    }
```

The real difference comes when one goes to use the typeclass. While in the case of a typeclass, you get access to the dictionary implicitly,

```
f :: MyNum t => t -> t -> t
f a b = mul a (add a b)
```

whereas in the case of the record of functions, one must explicitly provide a dictionary,

```
f :: MyNumDict t -> t -> t -> t
f dict a b = myMul a (myAdd a b)
  where myMul = mul dict
        myAdd = add dict
```

The implicit passing of the dictionary that typeclasses provide makes polymorphic code arguably much nicer to work with. That being said, they are easy to abuse.

I should also say that the role of typeclasses is no longer limited to polymorphism in the dictionary. For instance, recent type system extensions such as `TypeFamilies` use type classes as a means of implementing basic type level functions.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good use-case for the `Cancellative` typeclass from the `monoid-subclasses` package.

A `Cancellative` is essentially the same as a `Semigroup` but it also includes a "cancellation" method (similar to your `remove` method).

I also noted that you have an 'identity' method in your question but I don't see why that's needed for a sliding window aggregation. Hence, I went with a `Semigroup` rather than a `Group`.

Here is an implementation of a generic sliding window algorithm on an array of `Cancellative`s:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (nonEmpty)
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Semigroup.Cancellative

windowCalc :: Cancellative c
           => [c]
           -> Int
           -> (c -> ret)
           -> [ret]
windowCalc ar k agg =
    case nonEmpty $ take k ar of
        Just ne ->
            let
                first = sconcat ne
            in
                calc first $ zip ar (drop k ar)
            where
                calc cur ar =
                    agg cur :
                        case ar of
                            (front, back) : xs ->
                                let
                                    Just next = back <> cur </> front
                                in
                                    calc next xs
                            [] -> []
        Nothing -> []
```

There is already an implementation of `Cancellative` for summation ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-subclasses-1.2.1/docs/Data-Semigroup-Cancellative.html#t:SumCancellative)) so you can use the code above for a summing sliding window as follows:

```
testArr :: [Sum Int]
testArr = fmap (\x -> Sum x) [1 .. 10]

test :: [Int]
test = windowCalc testArr 3 (\x -> getSum x)


main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show test
```

which prints:

```
[6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27]
```